Graphics card unsupported
So ive been trying to install a later version of Blender on my laptop. Currently running 3.4.1.
Ive done work on my desktop in 4.1 and obviously cant open files in 3.4. but i believe 3.6 can open 4.1 files.
My laptop is a Sony Vaio Intel Corei5, 12gb ram intel HD 4000 (2GB) which so Intel says, should support OpenGL 4. I cant find any drivers at all... Any help or info is appreciated.

I'd try opening your work in Blender 4.0, and then saving it, and then opening again in latest 3.6.

what often works is just importing all objects from that blend file.

Starting from Blender 4.0 you need GPU that supports OpenGL 4.3, however the maximum version supported by Intel HD 4000 is 4.0.
If the scene saved in Blender 4.0-4.1 does not work, you might try the following options:

Launch Blender using software OpenGL by downloading DLL from here and copying it into the Blender's installation folder.

Export your scene using some intermediate format, such as FBX/USD/Alembic and import it in the older version of Blender.


